# What events occur when I enter text into a field? What text encoding is my input in?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, character-encoding

I'm using the keyboard to enter multi-lingual text into a field in a form displayed by a Web browser.  At an O/S-agnostic and browser-agnostic level, I think the following events take place (please correct me if I'm wrong, because I think I am):

1. On each keypress, there is an interrupt indicating a key was pressed
2. The O/S (or the keyboard driver?) determines the keycode and converts that to some sort of keyboard event (character, modifiers, etc).
3. The O/S' window manager looks for the currently-focused window (the browser) and passes the keyboard event to it
4. The browser's GUI toolkit looks for the currently-focused element (in this case, the field I'm entering into) and passes the keyboard event to it
5. The field updates itself to include the new character
6. When the form is sent, the browser encodes the entered text before sending it to the form target (what encoding?)

Before I go on, is this what actually happens?  Have I missed or glossed over anything important?

Next, I'd like to ask: how is the character represented at each of the above steps?  At step 1, the keycode could be a device-specific magic number.  At step 2, the keyboard driver could convert that to something the O/S understands (for example, the USB HID spec: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class).  What about at subsequent steps?  I think the encodings at steps 3 and 4 are OS-dependent and application-dependent (browser), respectively.  Can they ever be different, and if yes, how is that problem resolved?

The reason I'm asking is I've run into a problem that is specific to a site that I started to use recently:

[image]

Things appear to be working until step 6 above, where the form with the entered text gets submitted, after which the text is mangled beyond recognition.  While it's pretty obvious the site isn't handling Unicode input correctly, the incident has led me to question my own understanding of how things work, and now I'm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anatomy of a character from key press to application:

1 - The PC Keyboard:

PC keyboards are not the only type of keyboard, but I'll restrict myself to them.
PC Keyboards surprisingly enough do not understand characters, they understand keyboard buttons. This allows the same hardware used by a US keyboard to be used for QEWERTY or Dvorak and for English in any other language that uses the US 101/104-key format (some languages have extra keys.)

Keyboards use standard scan codes to identify the keys, and to make matters more interesting keyboards can be configured to use a specific set of codes:

Set 1 - used in the old XT keyboards
Set 2 - used currently and 
Set-3 used by PS/2 keyboards which no one uses today.

Sets 1 and 2 use make and break codes (i.e. press down and release codes). Set 3 uses make and break codes just for some keys (like shift) and only make codes for letters this allows the keyboard itself to handle key repeat when the key is pressed for long. This is good to offload key repeat processing from the PS/2 8086 or 80286 processor but rather bad for gaming.

You can read more about all this [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-10.html) and I also found a [Microsoft specification for scan codes](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc) in case you want to build and certify your own 104 key windows keyboard.

In any case we can assume a PC Keyboard using set 2, which means it sends to the computer a code when a key is pressed and one when a key is released.
By the way the USB HID spec does not specify the scan codes sent by the keyboard it only specifies the structures used to send those scan codes.
Now since we're talking about hardware this is true for all operating systems, but how every operating system handles these codes may differ. I'll restrict myself to what happens in Windows, but I assume other operating systems should follow roughly the same path.

2 - The Operating System

I don't know exactly how exactly Windows handles the keyboard, which parts are handled by drivers, which by the kernel and which in user mode; but suffice to say the keyboard is periodically polled for changed to key state and the scan codes are translated and converted to WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP messages which contain [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
To be precise Windows also generates WM_SYSKEYUP/WM_SYSKEYDOWN messages and you can read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

3 - The Application

For Windows that is it, the application gets the raw virtual key codes and it is up to it to decide to use them as is or translate them to a character code.
Nowadays nobody writes good honest C windows programs, but once upon a time programmers used to roll out their own message pump handling code and most message pumps would contain code similar to:

```
while (GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) != 0)
{ 
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

TranslateMessage is where the magic happens. The code in TranslateMessage would keep track of the WM_KEYDOWN (and WM_SYSKEYDOWN) messages and generate WM_CHAR messages (and WM_DEADCHAR, WM_SYSCHAR, WM_SYSDEADCHAR.)
WM_CHAR messages contain the UTF-16 (actually the UCS-2 but lets not split hairs) code for the character translated from the WM_KEYDOWN message by taking into account the active keyboard layout at the time.
What about application written before unicode? Those applications used the ANSI version of RegisterClassEx (i.e. RegisterClassExA) to register their windows. In this case TranslateMessage generated WM_CHAR messages with an 8 bit character code based on the keyboard layout and the active culture.

4 - 5 - Dispatching and displaying characters.

In modern code using UI libraries it is entirely possible (though unlikely) not to use TranslateMessage and have custom translation of WM_KEYDOWN events. Standard Window controls (widgets) understand and handle WM_CHAR messages dispatched to them, but UI libraries/VMs running under windows can implement their own dispatch mechanism and many do.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you.  I only have one point to make: I'm not sure if keyboard input in Windows is interrupt-driven or poll-based (or a mixture of both), but that isn't as relevant here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834961/is-the-cpu-wasted-waiting-for-keyboard-input-generic

Answer (score 1):

Your description is more or less correct.

However it is not essential to understand what is wrong with the site.

The question marks instead of characters indicate a translation between encodings has taken place, as opposed to a misrepresentation of encodings (which would probably result in gibberish.)

The characters used to represent letters can be encoded in different ways. For example 'a' in ASCII is 0x61, but 0x81 in EBCDIC. This you probably know, what people tend to forget is that ASCII is a 7 bit code containing only English characters. Since PC computers use bytes as their storage unit, early on the unused top 128 places in the ASCII code where used to represent letters in other alphabets, but which one? Cyrillic? Greek? etc..
DOS used code page numbers to specify which symbols where used. Most (all?) of the DOS code pages left the lower 128 symbols unchanged so English looked like English no matter what code page was used; but try to use a Greek code page to read a Russian text file and you'd end up with Greek and symbols gibberish.

Later Windows added it's own encodings some of the with variable length encodings (as opposed to DOS code pages in which each character was represented by a single byte code,) and then Unicode came along introducing the concept of code points.

Under code points each character is assigned a code point identified by a generic number, i.e. the code point is identified by a number not a 16 bit number.
Unicode also defined encodings to encode code points into bytes. UCS-2 is a fixed length encoding that encodes the code point numbers as 16 bit numbers. What happens to code points with more than 16 bits, simple they cannot be encoded in UCS-2.
When translating from an encoding that supports a specific code point to one that doesn't the character is replaced with a specified character, usually the question mark.

So if I get a transmission in UTF-16 with the hebrew character aleph 'א' and translate it to say latin-1 encoding which has no such character (or formally latin-1 has no code point to represent the unicode code point U+05D0) I'll get a question mark character instead '?'

What is happening in the web site is exactly that, it is getting your input just fine but it is being translated into an encoding that does not support all the characters in your input.

Unfortunately, unlike encoding misrepresentations which can be fixed by manually specifying the encoding of the page there is nothing you can do to fix this on the client.

A related problem is using fonts that do not have the characters shown. In this case you'd see a blank square instead of the character. This problem can be fixed on the client by overriding the site CSS or installing appropriate fonts.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I am familiar with Unicode, and I understand what is wrong with the site.  I'm more interested in what exactly happens before step 6.  How are the input characters being represented at each step?

Comment: I'll try and answer your question later though I fear I may not get all the details right. As for step 6 the encoding used should be ruled by the "accept-charset" header/html attribute.